Firefox rendering a slight black outline around my video on my site and I cannot remove it
I have a video on my next.js app and on chrome it is being rendered perfectly but on Firefox it is being rendered with a slight black outline and I can't remove it. Does anyone know how? On Chrome it is just fine with no outline.
Here is the code where the video is in my main page:
<div className="h-[100vh] w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-[-10vh]">
              <GifLikeVideo 
                src="/Vid1.mp4"
                width={440}
                height={160}
                
              />
              <p>
                <span 
                  className="text-2xl"
                  style={{ 
                    fontWeight: 500, 
                    fontSize: '1.2rem',
                    textShadow: '0 0 0.3px currentColor'
                  }}
                >
                  Example 
                </span> 
                {" "}In this video you will see a full example.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

I tried various different kinds of !important CSS styles but none of them have worked.
Here are two unsuccessful attempts I tried in my global.css file
Attempt 1
video, .GifLikeVideo {
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

Attempt 2
/* Global CSS */
video {
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

